# bouncing ball animation in javascript

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is Theme of my javascript game-

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/nHfXV/1/)

When ball touches offset to X,Y paddle then it should stop moving. I think current axis should be known for that but somehow i can't find any way.
Please help me making it more real.

This is my draw function-

```
function draw() {
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
      ctx.rect(mouseX-40,mouseY-20,40,20,true);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x,y,10,0,2*Math.PI,true);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
      x+=dx;
      y+=dy;
      bounce();
    }
```

Conditions i put here-

```
function bounce(){
      if(x+dx>300||x+dx<0)
        dx=-dx;
      if(y+dy>300||y+dy<0)
        dy=-dy;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ball to stop moving when it hits the paddle you could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/nHfXV/2/

```
if(x+dx<mouseX&&x+dx>mouseX-40&&y+dy<mouseY&&y+dy>mouseY-20){
    dy=0;
    dx=0;
}
```